# Xcode Eureka Loop with SegmentedRow crashes when selecting an option

Tags: ios, xcode, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka plugin for xcode swift and having an issue with the app crashing when selecting option "OTHER". It's supposed to have a TextRow below the date if "OTHER" is selected.

Error: Thread 1: Assertion failed: Duplicate tag segments

I'm pretty sure the issue is with `<<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){` not being incremented "segments1", "segments2", etc... with each looped row. Also I do not know how I could make the `$0.hidden` line work if segments had to be incremented:  `$0.hidden = "$segments != 'OTHER'"`

```
form
            +++ Section()

            for (index, date) in fdates.enumerated() {
                form.last!
                <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
                    $0.title = date
                    $0.options = ["FULL", "AM", "PM", "OTHER"]
                    $0.value = "FULL"
                    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in

                        cell.segmentedControl.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

                        if (self.type == "Lieu") {
                            cell.segmentedControl.setWidth(CGFloat(47), forSegmentAt: 0)
                            cell.segmentedControl.setWidth(CGFloat(40), forSegmentAt: 1)
                            cell.segmentedControl.setWidth(CGFloat(40), forSegmentAt: 2)
                            cell.segmentedControl.setWidth(CGFloat(57), forSegmentAt: 3)
                        }

                        //print(index)
                    }

                +++ Section(){
                    $0.tag = "other_\(index)"
                    $0.hidden = "$segments != 'OTHER'" 
                }
                <<< TextRow(){
                    $0.title = "This will be changed to a time picker after..."
                }
            }
```

** **EDIT** ** I managed to stop the crashing by using the index row with "segments" but the TextRow still doesn't show up when clicking "OTHER":

```
let tag = "segments\(index)"
<<< SegmentedRow<String>(tag){

+++ Section(){
    $0.tag = "other\(index)"
    $0.hidden = Condition(stringLiteral: "$segments\(index) != 'OTHER'")
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author told me to move the `form +++ Section()` into the loop just before `<<< SegmentedRow<String>(tag){` and this works.

```
for (index, date) in fdates.enumerated() {
    form +++ Section()
    let tag = "segments\(index)"
     <<< SegmentedRow<String>(tag){
         $0.title = date
```